# Weird time formating with chart.js and moment.js

Tags: chart.js, momentjs

Every second I'm updating my chart with new data, where label is correct unix timestamp. Here's options for my x-axis

```
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 0,
            minRotation: 0,
          },
          type: "time",
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              second: "HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

I'm wondering to get from timestamp `1535577869` something like `21:24:29` but getting `9:32:57.871 pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript timestamp (see [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)) is in milliseconds, not seconds like a Unix timestamp.

To make moment.js recognise your timestamp you probably need to multiply it by a thousand (since Chart.js is passing your value to moment.js):

```
1535577869 * 1000
```

If you were creating a moment directly you could [specify an input format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
moment(1535577869, 'X');
```